# Setup for Giant's Keep

Tags: summoners-war

What are the most effective of my monsters for Giant's Keep B7 and up?

My monsters;

Fairy King-Fire 5*

Chimera- Fire 5*

Arang- Wind 5*

Beast Monk- Water 5*

Belledeon- Light 4*

Raoq- Fire 4*

Barbarian King- Fire 4*

Megan-Water 4*

Magic Knight- Water 5*

Bernard- Wind 5*

Undine- Fire 5*

Anubus-Water 5*

Konamya- Water 3*

***Answer based on speed clearing please(or possible clearing).***

Comment: I think your best bet would be to limit to a) a certain dungeon, and b) less focus on what you have. Questions are here to help future readers as well, not just yourself. We generally frown on questions that go, "Here's what I have, make it better."

Comment: Frank is correct. If you having an issue clearing a specific dungeon, that is the sort of answer we deal with here. We do not answer broad gameplay answers. For example, if you having an issue clearing something because you are confused about the concepts and strategies involved in that dungeon, then we would be able to pinpoint answer your question. As it is now, we can not give you a suitable answer that covers the entire single player experience.

Comment: Is that okay now?

Comment: Looks ok to me now, but I'm a little biased.

Comment: @John Retracted my close vote. The question is better now and shouldn't be closed

Comment: There's no best setup for monsters. You also need the proper runes for your mons.

Comment: Be more specific. What monsters are to be included, excluded.. can you get your hands on Fusions, any Nat5s?

Comment: Edit your favourite monsters into the question please and try to answer my questions as well: can you get Fusion mons or have some already? Or only farmable mons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To separate a save team from a speed team I'll post this as new answer instead.

Your ultimate goal is to clear Giants B10 in around 1 minute. There are faster ones with ~30 seconds, but that will require A LOT of work and is likely opinion based, because there are a few options people often discuss on Reddit.

Monsters you'll find useful for a speed team:

- Lushen (Wind Joker)
- Theomars (Water Ifrit)
- Galleon (Water Pirate Captain)
- Sigmarus (Water Phoenix)
- *something useful* [see below]

Lushen is important to quickly clear the trash waves, Theo and Sig are good at single nuking, while Sig also helps effectively clearing the trash. Galleon is a 2-in-1 Buffer and Debuffer and absolutely worth it.

[*Your 5th Monster*]

In DB10 Tarq (Water Hellhound) is pure win compared to how easy you get him. He also does a pretty decent job in GB10. You can as well bring Vero (Dark Ifrit) or Orochi (Wind Ninja) and use their DoTs to bring down the boss. Vero also helps CCing the trash.

Comment: Any idea on what team with my current monsters?

Comment: @John Belladeon is somewhat useful there for speed clearings (def break, atk bar) or maybe Megan if you can't get your hands on Galleon. Most supporters or Fire monsters only slow things down.

Comment: So 5* Bella and Megan?

Comment: And maybe Konamya?

Comment: @John Kona is an option to run it more smoothly, but not actually faster. Also you need your damage dealers to be 6* in order to actually get some speed.

Comment: I'm farming for runes now. What is a good monster to 6* for farming?

Comment: @John that depends on where you farm. Since the scenarios all have different elements there is no all-in-one farmer. In general you should 6-star your Faimon farmer and/or allrounders like Belladeon. Belladeon is one of the first mons you should 6*, because you'll need him quite a lot.

Answer (score 3):

By the lack of useful monsters you should probably try to learn how to use "lower tier" monsters. There's a bunch of 2* and 3* monsters that are really important and those can help you getting through the dungeons with ease without being Nat5*.
Also it is more important to run the dungeon safely first. If you've done that you can try to get more speed in it (but that requires monsters that are a lot harder to get).

You should take some time farming a good team in order to tackle the dungeons properly. They're hard to beat for a reason. Also a few good monsters suitable for Giants can also be used elsewhere.

This is a good composition to tackle Giants B9 and 10, which should be your goal at the end of the day. For B8 you might want to bring something different. Veromos or Beretta as leader make things easier (instead of Konamiya). The other 4 mons are absolutely worth it in all three stages.

```
Monster                     |   Where to get it
----                        -   -----
Bernard (Wind Griffon)      |   Tamor Desert, Mystical Scroll, Wind Scroll, ...
Konamiya (Water Garuda)     |   Unknown Scroll, Shop, Secret Dungeon,...
Darion (Light Vagabond)     |   Secret Dungeon
Belladeon (Light Inugami)   |   Secret Dungeon
Shannon (Wind Pixie)        |   Unknown Scroll, Shop, Secret Dungeon,...
```

As you can see you don't need any Nat4* or 5* to succeed in Giants.